# How to create a key-value dictionary with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to create a key-value dictionary with the following output

```
"a"
true
"b"
true
"c"
false
```

I try with thirst to put a colon after each value but it is not possible.

The format should be as follows:

```
"a": true, "b": true, "c": false
```

this is the command I am trying:

`awk '{print $1":"$2","}'`

and this is de fail output:

`"a":, true:, "b":, true:, "c":, false:,`

Comment: Do you want to create a dictionary in your custom format _or_ you want a json?

Comment: I need this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use paste:

```
$ paste -sd':,' file
"a":true,"b":true,"c":false
```

Since `paste` only accepts input from a file, if you have a string, you would do:

```
$ paste -sd':,' <(echo "$your_str")
```

If you need the space after the `,` and `:` you can add them:

```
$ paste -sd':,' file | sed -E 's/([:,])/\1 /g'
"a": true, "b": true, "c": false
```

Or if you really want an awk:

```
$ awk  'NR%2{id=$1; next}
{s=s dlm id ": " $1; dlm=", "}
END{ print s }' file
"a": true, "b": true, "c": false
```

Comment: awk helped me, I didn't want to use paste because we would have to install it in the gitlap runners.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another simple awk solution:

```
awk -v ORS='' '
    NR>1 { print( NR%2 ? ", " : ": " ) }
    1;
    END { print "\n" }
' inputfile
```

---

The reason your code didn't work is that awk reads input a "record" at a time (by default, line by line). So your `$2` is always empty.

Comment: variant that ignores lines containing only whitespace: `awk -v ORS='' '!$1{next} i++{print(i%2?", ":": ")} 1; END{print"\n"}' inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

`print $1":"$2","` references the 1st and 2nd fields from the *current* line, but you're requirement is to process fields from *multiple* lines, so you'll need to store the 1st line in a variable and then reference this variable when processing the 2nd line.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NR % 2 { key=$1; next }                          # odd numbered line, save 1st field in variable "key"
       { printf sep key ": " $1; sep=", "}       # even numbered line, print key/value to stdout; sep is blank 1st time we reference it, and then we set it to ", " for all further references
END    { print "" }                              # terminate output line
' file
```

This generates:

```
"a": true, "b": true, "c": false
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  mawk 'ORS = ORS < "&" && RS < ORS ? ", " : " : "' |
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  mawk 7 RS='[\7-/]+$'
> ```

```
"a" : true, "b" : true, "c" : false
```